# Freeswitch sdp response missing digest

Tags: javascript, webrtc, digest, freeswitch, sdp

I have a mysterious issue with Freeswitch 1.6.6.

I try to integrate **sipjs** (v0.7.4) to work with my central using webrtc.

The application have no problem to register (using wss) but when I try to call an other user, I have a sdp parsing error:

```
SIPml-api.js:1 Failed to parse SessionDescription. a=fingerprint:sha-256
Failed to create fingerprint from the digest.tsk_utils_log_error @ SIPml-api.js:1
```

When I check the sdp in the freeswitch logs this is what I receive (IP adresse are voluntary masked):

```
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-45.0.2 3927228173093566425 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 EE:D6:5C:B1:7D:99:E6:FB:9A:46:89:58:14:19:A5:29:4A:AF:D3:0D:BE:32:06:76:1D:08:F5:3F:F9:DA:8B:DA
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 63339 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8
c=IN IP4 ***.***.***.***
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000/1
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 ***.***.***.*** 63339 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122187007 ***.***.***.*** 54708 typ host
a=candidate:4 1 UDP 2122121471 ***.***.***.*** 56942 typ host
a=candidate:0 2 UDP 2122252542 ***.***.***.*** 61720 typ host
a=candidate:2 2 UDP 2122187006 ***.***.***.*** 61984 typ host
a=candidate:4 2 UDP 2122121470 ***.***.***.*** 63345 typ host
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ice-pwd:1caa7d986c87c16de3e4f6f760528544
a=ice-ufrag:2e86561a
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{2b638262-0603-3942-af0e-24fcb578a272} {5b012d42-d929-c144-8669-4aa5367cb6be}
a=rtcp:61720 IN IP4 ***.***.***.***
a=rtcp-mux
a=setup:actpass
a=ssrc:1176697136 cname:{04e0f7d1-9999-ad46-871c-55dcb58e8bbd}
```

And this is what Freeswitch send to the client:

```
v=0
o=FreeSWITCH 1461635251 1461635252 IN IP4 128.179.101.13
s=FreeSWITCH
c=IN IP4 ***.***.***.***
t=0 0
a=msid-semantic: WMS SqfRSSh9myFLk84BEDbOTgfOjB1zYaUH
m=audio 23832 RTP/SAVPF 109 9 0 8 102 101
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:109 useinbandfec=1; maxaveragebitrate=510000; maxplaybackrate=48000; ptime=20; minptime=10; maxptime=40; stereo=1
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:102 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fingerprint:sha-256 
a=setup:actpass
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:23832 IN IP4 ***.***.***.***
a=ssrc:1503282107 cname:qZo9Iv9VTEx4Drv7
a=ssrc:1503282107 msid:SqfRSSh9myFLk84BEDbOTgfOjB1zYaUH a0
a=ssrc:1503282107 mslabel:SqfRSSh9myFLk84BEDbOTgfOjB1zYaUH
a=ssrc:1503282107 label:SqfRSSh9myFLk84BEDbOTgfOjB1zYaUHa0
a=ice-ufrag:VxMFDRjNjad7bYEs
a=ice-pwd:OTsmer8YVvSpNenyCZ36HdJQ
a=candidate:2992776492 1 udp 659136 ***.***.***.*** 23832 typ host generation 0
a=candidate:2992776492 2 udp 659136 ***.***.***.*** 23832 typ host generation 0
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv
```

Has you can see, there no sha-256 digest in the Freeswitch sdp.

Does anyone have an idea why the digest disappear ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see message like `[ERR] switch_core_cert.c:210 FP FILE ERR!`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are missing dtls-srtp.pem in your $${certs_dir}

Check the ownership of your freeswitch dir, user that is running freeswitch needs to have permitions on $${certs_dir} usually /etc/freeswitch/tls to create dtls-srtp.pem cert.

Comment: This file was missing. It's because I use a docker container and I link the certs directory with one on the host. So the dtls-srtp.pem file was destroy.
I had to restart freeswitch in the container for the reconstruction of this file (docker start/stop don't recreate the file).
Thanks for the answer

Comment: np, glad it was fixed :)